# Undecidability of TMs recognizing a decidable language

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

The language $L = \{ \text{M} \mid \text{M  is a TM and the set of words w such that M halts on w is decidable} \}$ is given.

I need to prove that $L$ is NOT Turing recognizable. I've got a hint: it should be similar to prove to the Rice Theorem, using a reduction. However, this hint isn't very helpful to me.

Comment: Can you add a bit more details to the questions? Is there a **specific** issue that you're having in trying to complete a proof? Probably nobody will be very happy to solve your exercises...

Comment: currently, I am unable to find/think of any solution .... the only hint i've got is that the reduction should be something like rice proof.

Answer (score 1):

1. You want to prove that the language of deciders—the language of Turing machines whose language is decidable—is not recognizable.
2. To prove this by reduction, we need to show that if we assume we have a recognizer $f(M)$ for the language—that is, it correctly outputs YES for every decider $M$ and either runs forever or returns NO for non-deciders—then we can use $f(M)$ as a subroutine to build a recognizer for some unrecognizable language. Because this is impossible, it will establish that no such recognizer $f$ exists, QED.
3. Here is one common example of an unrecognizable language: The language $\overline{A}_{TM}$ of all pairs (M,w) where M is a Turing machine that runs forever on input w. (This is the complement of the halting problem.)
4. If we have a subroutine $f(M)$ that recognizes whether M is a decider, I claim we can build a TM that recognizes $\overline{A}_{TM}$. Because that's impossible, this construction will prove by contradiction that $f$ doesn't exist, which shows that the language of decidable Turing machines is *not* actually recognizable.
5. In the proof, it will be useful to have an example of a decidable and undecidable language.

   - Let $H(M,w)$ be the Turing machine that simply simulates $M$ on $w$ and returns YES if the simulation halts (or runs forever if the simulation does). Note that the language of $H$ is the language of (M,w) such that M halts on input w—the halting problem—so it's an **undecidable language**. $H$ is *not a decider*.
   - Let $E(x)$ be the Turing machine that ignores its input and loops forever. The language of $E$ is empty $\varnothing$, which is a **decidable language**. $E$ *is a decider*.
6. We're aiming to solve the $\overline{A}_{TM}$ problem ("Does M loop forever on input w?") using a subroutine for solving the decider problem ("Is M a Turing machine with a decidable language?").

   To relate these two problems together, it would be useful if we could take in (M,w) for the $\overline{A}_{TM}$ problem and convert it into a machine $\tilde M$ whose language is decidable if and only if $M$ loops forever on input $w$. That way, we can recognize whether (M,w) is in $\overline{A}_{TM}$ by recognizing (using $f$) whether $\tilde M$ is a decider.

   We can do exactly that! Given an input (M,w), we will cleverly design a new machine $\tilde M$ which behaves like $E$ if M loops forever on w, or behaves like $H$ if M halts on w.  In other words, $\tilde M$ has a decidable language if M loops forever on w, and has an undecidable language if M halts on w.

Here's how to do it:

> Given an input (M,w), define $\tilde M$ as the machine which first ignores its input and just simulates $M$ on $w$. If that simulation halts, then the machine passes its input to $H$ and returns whatever $H$ returns.

Note that if M loops forever on w, then $\tilde M$ loops forever on all inputs and hence has an empty language. If M accepts w, then $\tilde M$ just does whatever $H$ does. Because $H$ has an undecidable language, $\tilde M$ has an undecidable language in this case.

7. Finally, here's a recognizer for $\overline{A}_{TM}$:
   > Given an input (M,w), construct the machine $\tilde M$ which first ignores its input and just simulates $M$ on $w$. If that simulation halts, then the machine passes its input to $H$ and returns whatever $H$ returns.
   >
   > Feed this new TM $\tilde M$ into $f$ and return its answer.
8. As with many reduction proofs, this proof relies on a convoluted construction. It requires some explanation.

   Note that this definition cleverly makes the language of $M^\prime$ depend on whether M loops forever on w or not:

   If M loops forever on input w, then $M^\prime$ will loop forever trying to simulate it. So in this case $M^\prime$ never accepts anything — its language is empty. Hence $M^\prime$ will have a decidable language.

   If M halts on input w, then $M^\prime$ will always pass its input to $H$ and return whatever it does. In this case, the language of $M^\prime$ will just be the language of $H$, which is undecidable. Hence $M^\prime$ will have an undecidable language.

   Therefore, to recognize whether M loops forever on input w, just compute $f(M^\prime)$. If this subroutine returns YES (M' is a decider), you return YES (M loops forever on input w).

   This is a recognizer for $\overline{A}_{TM}$, which we know is impossible, therefore $f$ (a recognizer for whether a TM is a decider) can't actually exist, QED.

Answer (score 0):

Given a machine $A$, construct a machine $M$ which on input $x$, acts as follows: run $A$ on the empty input, and if it ever halts, run the Turing machine encoded by $x$ on the empty input.

If $A$ halts on the empty input then the language $M$ recognizes is the halting language, while if $A$ doesn't halt on the empty input then the language $M$ recognizes is the empty language.

Comment: i don't see how this solves or proves the question ...